# How do I test a function that expects e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> as a parameter?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

How do I unit test the `doStuff` method below without having to create a full blown `React.ChangeEvent` object?

```
// my-form.tsx
export const doStuff = (changeHandler: ChangeHandler, e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  // A call to another function takes place here, but for brevity, I'm using console.log
  console.log(e); 
  changeHandler(e);
}

interface ChangeHandler {
  (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void;
}

interface MyFormProps {
  changeHandler: ChangeHandler,
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

const MyForm: React.SFC<MyFormProps> = ({changeHandler, username, password}) => (
  <form>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="username"
        value={username}
        onChange={doStuff.bind(null, changeHandler)} />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={doStuff.bind(null, changeHandler)} />
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
);

export default MyForm;
```

Below is my test file.  The first test is what I'd like to do in order to test `doStuff`.  The 2nd test, I believe, is how I can also test `doStuff`.

```
// my-form.test.tsx
import MyForm, { doStuff } from './my-form.tsx';

describe('MyForm' => {
  it('should call the changeHandler', () => {
    // Arrange
    const changeHandlerMock = jest.fn();

    // Act
    // How can I pass a mock for the 2nd parameter?
    // doStuff(changeHandlerMock, {});

    // Assert
    expect(changeHandlerMock.called.length).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('should call the changeHandler too', () => {
    // Arrange
    const changeHandlerMock = jest.fn();

    // Act
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <MyForm
        changeHandler={changeHandlerMock}
        username={username}
        password={password} />
    );
    wrapper.find(`input[name='username']`).simulate('change');

    // Assert
    expect(changeHandlerMock.called.length).toEqual(1);
  })
});
```

Alternatively, I can get rid of `doStuff` and change the markup, for each input element, to:

```
onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  console.log(e);
  changeHandler(e);
}} />
```

The downside is that if I need to make changes to the eventHandler, I'll have to do it in every place it's declared, hence the `doStuff` method.

For completeness, here is my container component:

```
interface MyFormContainerState {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

// my-form-container.tsx
class MyFormContainer extends React.Component<{}, MyFormContainerState> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  public render() {
    const { username, password } = this.state;

    return (
      <MyForm
        changeHandler={this.changeHandler}
        username={username}
        password={password} />
    );

  }

  public changeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass the type checking for your mocked object by using a [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to assert the type as [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

```tsx
it('should call the changeHandler', () => {
  // Arrange
  const changeHandlerMock = jest.fn();

  // Act
  doStuff(changeHandlerMock, {} as any);

  // Assert
  expect(changeHandlerMock.called.length).toEqual(1);
});
```